# Regular expression for validating literals and alphanumeric character in string

Tags: regex, validation

We like to validate following with Regex:

1. string may contain 0 or more alphabets, digits, underscore OR
2. string may contain literals %sample1% or %sample2% (0 or more times in any order)

For example:
`%sample1%_%sample2%` is valid
`%sample2%%sample1%` is valid
`1_abc` is valid
`%sampleee1%` is not valid
`%sample2%%sample1%_%sample1%_%sample1%` is valid

we tried this:

`^(%sample1%)*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(%sample2%)*$`

but it is not matching following:

`%sample2%%sample1%`

What should be our `regex` in this case.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: In case 1, `string should contain alphabets, digits, underscore` does it need to contain all three or just one of the three? i.e., does just `A` match?

Comment: tried regex was already present in the question, instead of clubbing it in pipes, we were trying * on all three expressions separately, which was causing ordering issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex does what you want:

```
^(%sample1%|%sample2%|[a-zA-Z0-9_])*$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/zfWdo1iHPS)

Note that this may be shortened to:

```
^(%sample[12]%|\w)*$
```

Although you may not want to combine the "sample" terms, the regex `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (if you are expecting only latin characters - `\w` includes letters and digits from many languages).

Comment: Depending on the implementation, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` may not be synonymous with `\w`.  If operating under Unicode semantics, `\w` may match over 100000 different characters.

Comment: @DavidO but actually, had it not been for comments like that, I would not have learned this fact, so thanks for keeping me honest!

Comment: For reference, `perldoc perlre`, and `perldoc perluniprops`.  In modern Perl implementations, `\w` is synonymous with `\p{word}`, matching 103406 characters if the regexp engine is operating under `/u` Unicode semantics.

Comment: This regex will match a single `\w` character. i.e., `re.search(r'^(%sample[12]%|\w)*$', 'a')` would be true. I am not sure if that is intended...

Comment: @dawg could be, but the first constraint doesn't say letters *and* digits *and* underscore, it just mentions them as a list - I assumed "or" logic. A couple of look-aheads may be needed if it's meant to be "and" logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just break it down in code just the way you described it:

```
txt='''\
%sample1%_%sample2% is valid 
%sample2%%sample1% is valid 
1_abc is valid 
%sampleee1% is not valid 
%sample2%%sample1%%sample1%%sample1% is valid'''

import re

for line in txt.splitlines():
    print line.split(' ', 1)
    if re.search(r'_', line) and re.search(r'\d', line) and re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]', line):
        print 'valid #1'
    elif re.search(r'%sample\d+%', line):
        print 'valid #2'
    else:
        print 'not valid'
```

Prints:

```
['%sample1%_%sample2%', 'is valid ']
valid #1
['%sample2%%sample1%', 'is valid ']
valid #2
['1_abc', 'is valid ']
valid #1
['%sampleee1%', 'is not valid ']
not valid
['%sample2%%sample1%%sample1%%sample1%', 'is valid']
valid #2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also solve your problem:
^((%sample1%)*(%sample2%)*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*$